# Attempting to bootstrap and getting weird errors

Tags: macos, python

I'm on a new computer(mac 10.9.2) and I am attempting to bootstrap my companies project, but setuptools is failing.

I can run python bootstrap.py, which creates the ./bin/buildout, but when I run the buildout, it returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/buildout", line 17, in <module>
    import zc.buildout.buildout
  File "/Users/miah/Documents/realmassive/joson/eggs/zc.buildout-1.7.1-py2.7.    egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 40, in <module>
    import zc.buildout.download
  File "/Users/miah/Documents/realmassive/joson/eggs/zc.buildout-1.7.1-py2.7.    egg/zc/buildout/download.py", line 20, in <module>
    from zc.buildout.easy_install import realpath
  File "/Users/miah/Documents/realmassive/joson/eggs/zc.buildout-1.7.1-py2.7.    egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 29, in <module>
    import setuptools.archive_util
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/setuptools/archive_util.py", line     15, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name ContextualZipFile
```

I've attempted installing it via `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#unix-including-mac-os-x-curl` and homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar problem on a Debian system. It seems that something is broken in the latest version of setuptools (4.0.1) which was probably the version of setuptools you pulled down for a fresh install. I was able to get things working by cleaning out the bad install and forcing use of 3.8 with `pip install setuptools==3.8`

Comment: Worth noting that now simply upgrading setuptools versions (5.1 as of writing) also fixes this.

Comment: I hit this same problem with 5.3 in Windows

Comment: 5.1 has worked for me in the past week on Windows and Linux. Maybe they broke it again.